# Attempting to assign money to a user with a certain string in their steam name Glua

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I'm making a reward based system for having a username in a steam name and I have got this far so far

```
local XPTimer = 0

local XPTimer = CurTime() + 10

if(XPTimer <= CurTime()) then
    if string.find("SERVERNAME", ply:SteamName()) then
            starwarsrp.ply:AddMoney(500)
                            starwarsrp.notify(ply, 3, 4, "You were awarded £500 for being part of SERVERNAME team!")

        end
    else
        Msg("didnt work")
end
XPTimer = CurTime() + 10
```

I am receiving the "else" message in the console "didn't work" and the timer doesn't seem to be working. Is there a thing I am doing wrong here. I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by `string.find("SERVERNAME", ply:SteamName())`, you are trying to find `SteamName` value in `"SERVERNAME"` string, which is likely to fail all the time, unless your Steam name happens to be a sub-string of `SERVERNAME`. You were probably thinking about getting the value of `SERVERNAME` environmental variable and for this you need to use `os.getenv("SERVERNAME")`, so something like `string.find(os.getenv("SERVERNAME") or "", ply:SteamName())` may work better (you need `or ""` as `os.getenv` may return `nil` when SERVERNAME is not set and `string.find` will throw an error on the `nil` passed to it).

Comment: Probably, it is `someTable.SERVERNAME`

Comment: I tried that and It still doesnt work. I get the error `attempt to call field 'getenv'`

Comment: It means that `os` table doesn't have `getenv` field (as you are probably running in a sandbox environment). Are you missing some table before `SERVERNAME` as Egor suggested?

Comment: how would I implement `someTable.SERVERNAME` would it be like this if `string.find(os.getenv(someTable.SERVERNAME) or "", ply:SteamName()) then`

Comment: No, Egor and I thought that maybe you have SERVERNAME as a field in one of the tables. Where are you trying to check for `ply:SteamName()`? Where do you expect `SERVERNAME` value to come from?

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not quite sure what you mean. Sorry I'm not very good at this

Comment: Why are you checking `"SERVERNAME"` string? Where do you get the reference from?

Comment: @Owen - Where did you see an example of code which uses `SERVERNAME`?

Comment: the "Servername" is a string, it will have the name of my server in there to compare

Comment: Then try with `string.find(SERVERNAME, ply:SteamName())` if it's a variable, but you need to make sure it's spelled *exactly* as needs to be (whether it's `Servername` or `SERVERNAME` or something else).

Comment: that's what I had originally up above but it didn't work